# How to add a single file exception to a rewrite rule that adds a slash to wp-admin by redirecting to HTTPS?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I need to change this so that one file in wp-admin is not forced through https:

```
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This forces all requests to /wp-admin through SSL but it is breaking a wordpress plugin which needs to access wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

Is there a way to adjust the rule so that it will allow non encrypted requests to that one file?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> This forces all requests to `/wp-admin` through SSL...

Actually, no it's not. As the code-comment states, it simply "adds a trailing slash to `/wp-admin`". It only targets URLs that *end in* `/wp-admin`, so it already excludes the URL `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. There is nothing more you need to do to these directives.

If `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` is being forced to HTTPS then *something else* is doing that (possibly even WordPress itself).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/wp-admin$
> RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/ [R=301,L]
> ```

*Aside:* The `RewriteCond` directive is not required here. This could arguably be simplified with just a single directive (which would also be more efficient):

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+/)?wp-admin$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional condition before your rule that does the redirect to https:

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Which will prevent the rewrite/redirect from occuring for this file

Comment: The current rule already has a condition that matches a specific URL, so this URL is already excluded! (Both can't be true.)

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested it, but this should do it...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
Redirect /directory/file.html http://domain.com/directory/file.html
```

Comment: thats for a folder. Will it work for a specific file URL? ALso, wouln't it be RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/somefolder$ ?

Comment: @codecowboy - Sorry, I was under the understanding you wanted it done for the entire directory. I have modified my answer.

Comment: `Redirect` is part of mod_alias, not mod_rewrite. However, even if you change this to use `RewriteRule`, it will still result in a redirect loop.